# Google-Bigquery: consolidate aggregate

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, aggregation, consolidation

I'm trying to create a query which does something a little complex, and I haven't been able to find anything that might point me in the right direction.  Perhaps YOU can help!

This is the source data:

```
7457, "05:06:26 UTC", 15
7457, "05:06:26 UTC", 15
7457, "05:06:26 UTC", 15
7457, "05:06:26 UTC", 15 
2341, "05:12:34 UTC", 10
2341, "05:12:34 UTC", 10
2341, "05:12:34 UTC", 10
2341, "05:12:34 UTC", 10
5678, "05:12:34 UTC", 15
5678, "05:12:34 UTC", 15
5678, "05:12:34 UTC", 15
5678, "05:12:34 UTC", 15
5678, "05:12:34 UTC", 15
5678, "05:12:34 UTC", 15
5678, "05:12:34 UTC", 15
5678, "05:12:34 UTC", 15
5678, "05:12:39 UTC", 15
5678, "05:12:39 UTC", 15
1111, "06:00:00 UTC", 10
2222, "07:00:00 UTC", 15
3333, "08:00:00 UTC", 10
```

I have a query to find duplicated stats:

```
SELECT userID, timestamp, statType, COUNT(*) - 1 AS DuplCount
FROM [dataset1.table1] 
GROUP BY userID, timestamp, statType 
HAVING DuplCount > 0;
```

(Note that only stats that have the same userID and timestamp can be considered duplicates.)

This results in a table that looks like

```
userID  timestamp       statType    DuplCount    
7457    05:06:26 UTC    15          3    
2341    05:12:34 UTC    10          3    
5678    05:12:34 UTC    15          7     
5678    05:12:39 UTC    15          1
```

I want to further consolidate this data so it can inserted as one row in another table: the sum of the counts of duplicates of the same statType.  I want it to look something like

```
table            stat10DuplCount  stat15DuplCount    
dataset1.table1  3                11
```

I'm not sure how to proceed...  can this all be done in one query (preferred), or do I need to do multiple queries or do some post-query data processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to do exactly what I want; the only difference between this query and Felipe's is that it takes the sum of the duplicates instead of counting each set of duplicates as one occurrence.

```
SELECT "dataset1.table1" table, SUM(IF(statID=10,DuplCount,null)) stat10DuplCount, SUM(IF(statID=15,DuplCount,null)) stat15DuplCount, 
FROM (
    SELECT userID, timestamp, statType, COUNT(*) - 1 AS DuplCount
    FROM [dataset1.table1] AS statsTable
    GROUP BY userID, timestamp, statType 
    HAVING DuplCount > 0
);
```

Which results in:

```
table            stat10DuplCount  stat15DuplCount    
dataset1.table1  3                11
```

Answer (score 2):

Sub-queries:

```
SELECT "dataset1.table1" table, COUNT(IF(statType=10,1,null)) stat10DuplCount, COUNT(IF(statType=15,1,null)) stat15DuplCount
FROM (
    SELECT userID, timestamp, statType, COUNT(*) - 1 AS DuplCount
    FROM [dataset1.table1] 
    GROUP BY userID, timestamp, statType 
    HAVING DuplCount > 0
)
```

(It's always easier to answer and test if you provide a working query that goes over a public dataset, or publish a sample of your data)

Working example:

```
SELECT "dataset1.table1" tablename,
       COUNT(IF(statType=10,1,null)) stat10DuplCount,
       COUNT(IF(statType=15,1,null)) stat15DuplCount
FROM (SELECT 15 statType),(SELECT 10 statType),(SELECT 15 statType),(SELECT 15 statType)

tablename       stat10DuplCount stat15DuplCount  
dataset1.table1 1               3
```

Comment: Thanks!  That definitely got me on the right track!